# C# Variable does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scope

(I know this question has been asked, but none of them work for me)

In my script, i have an array which is out of scope (which is strange because i'm following a tutorial which works). Can anyone see why the array is not in scope?

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public Transform[] PartolPoints;

    void Start () 
    {
        transform.position = PatrolPoints[0].position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I also noticed a typo: it was defined as PartrolPoints and i referenced PatrolPoints; sadly, removing it didn't fix the bug :(

Comment: Where is your array created/passed to `Start()` method?

Comment: Im using unity engine, you can specify what is assigned to PatrolPoints from outside the code

Comment: Well if PatrolPoints is not specified and passed as an empty array, then how will you access the index [0] on that array? Either ensure some validation at the point in which values are assigned to PatrolPoints, or do a check on the array before assigning it `if (PatrolPoints!= null && PatrolPoints.Length != 0) {//assign position from array} else {//error handling}` can also check on PatrolPoints[0]?

Comment: Ok, ill look into that. I have a solution that will work for the minute; i can assign a second list based on the first one, local to start (). It's not great, but it works for now at least

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the array at runtime?

If so, make sure you initialize the array in the Inspector by dragging your patrolpoint GameObjects into the array, or via Code by searching for your patrol points in the start() function.

Otherwise, if you have initialized your array correctly then you are getting out of the ordinary error and i recommend reinstalling the most recent release.

That code does work correctly, i confirmed it running the same version of unity on my side.